# Junit 4 - assertEqual isn't working on hashmap collection

Tags: java, junit

```
@Test
    public void checkbuildGraph_ifGraphExists() 
    {
        Graph expected =buildGraph(g1.name);
        
        assertEquals(expected.nodes, g1.nodes);
    }
```

I am tring to test buildgraph method that returns a built graph of Graph Object, then comparing it with hand made graph to check if they are equal. They are equal in terms of values not in terms of reference of course. Nonetheless, I am getting

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<[Node@3ada9e37]> but was:<[Node@2a3046da]>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:835)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:120)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:146)
    at TraceAnalyserTest.checkbuildGraph_ifGraphExists(TraceAnalyserTest.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Graph g1 is made in test class and expected is from a different class. I guess assertEqual is comparing the nodes based on their address not their values inside each object

Answer (score 1):

> I guess assertEqual is comparing the nodes based on their address not their values inside each object

`assertEqual` is comparing the nodes based on their `equals(Object)` methods.  It looks like they are inheriting theirs from class `Object`, which yields an identity comparison, equivalent to the `==` operator.  "Address" is not a native Java concept.

If you want to compare based on node values instead of node identities then you need to provide an `equals(Object)` implementation that will do so.  And if you do that, then you should also provide a `hashCode()` method consistent with your new `equals()` method, meaning that nodes that compare equal to each other are certain to also have the same hash code.

If you cannot override the nodes' `equals(Object)` methods then you cannot use `assertEquals()` in the way you are trying to do.  But you *could* write a custom assertion method in your test class or in a helper class that would  do the job you want for you.